Could any one tell any information on these characters on a piece of bronze
Could any one tell any information on these characters on a piece of bronze

弘璧《嚴感應緣起傳》：「然圓一部之典。纔獲三萬餘言。惟啟半珠。未窺全寶。朕聞其梵本。先在于闐國中。遣使奉迎。近方至此。既覩百千之妙頌。乃披十萬之正文。」

Is this from the Huayan Sutra please?

Yes, that's right
